# Transit visa for France while traveling to Fiji?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit

I am travelling to Fiji from the USA.  I have a layover of 12 hrs in Paris.  Will I require transit visa for the stop in Paris?  I will not leave the airport.  I am a Fijian Citizen.